# Уведомления Android. Непонятное поведение activity

Tags: android, activity, android-notification, pendingintent

У меня есть простой чат.

Диалог посетителей и администратора. Т.е. максимум только между 2-мя участниками. Для получения сообщений в режиме онлайн и определения кому должно придти сообщение я использую отправку в FireBase RealTime Database.

Например. Администратор имеет 2 разных диалога. С **юзером_1** и **юзером_2**

Для имитации я запускаю в студии 2 виртуальных устройства. Первое **админ**, второе **юзер_2**. И пишу с админа ему.

Чтобы определить что письмо должно отправиться **юзеру_2**, а не юзеру_1 в приложении я реализую слушатель.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
...
здесь я перебираю в RealTime все новые сообщения и показываю только то, где адресат я (юзер_2)

...
}
```

Всё работает отлично. Теперь мне нужно реализовать уведомления о новых сообщениях.

Задача в том, что уведомления должны быть только если пользователь свернул работающее приложение. И вот тут для меня начинается большая странность.

Когда приложение сворачивается, вызывается метод *onPause* и *onStop*

Тогда по умолчанию я сделал переменную *String proverka = "no";*

Когда приложение свёрнуто в методе *onStop* я назначаю *proverka = "yes";*

И в слушатель дополнительно задаю условие для уведомления

```
if (proverka.equals("yes")) 
{

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListMessages.class);

intent.putExtra("id_d", dialog_id);  // Задаю ИД диалога, что бы знать куда возвращаться
intent.putExtra("user_to", user_db); // Здесь помещаю отправителя, для показа в уведомлении от кого

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), 
CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(...)
                            .setContentTitle("Сообщение от " user_db)
                            .setContentText(...)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);


NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = 
NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
notificationManager.notify(47457, builder.build());

}
```

Т.е. если приложение сворачивается, при вызове онСтоп я задаю переменной "yes", а в слушателе FireBase я проверяю эту переменную, если она стала "yes", то показываю уведомления у нужного пользователя. А при нажатии на уведомление вызывается метод onResume, где я задаю переменной опять "no". Разворачивается приложение и уведомления не должны приходить.

Всё работает прекрасно если я сворачиваю приложение и разворачиваю опять. НО! Если я разворачиваю приложение по переходу через уведомление, не смотря на то что при onResume опять назначается "no", каким то образом при запуске слушателя FireBase переменная опять становится "yes" и уведомления показываются даже при развёрнутом приложении. Всю голову сломал почему так происходит

Comment: Хочу отметить, что реализация переменной proverka которая принимает только 2 явных значения, надо перевести в boolean

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память - пробовал. Результат такой же. Было бы конечно интересно разгадать загадку

Answer (score 0):

Как мне здесь подсказали, это и оказался верный ответ. Необходимо вместо переменных использовать сохранения данных в SharedPreferences. Там же менять и их же проверять